# Как отрисовать прямоугольник посредством протягивания зажатой левой кнопки мыши на scene до ее разжатия?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, qgraphicsscene

Как нарисовать прямоугольник с помощью протягивания зажатой левой кнопки мыши (**`ЛКМ`**) до ее разжатия (с изменением размера) ?

В моей программе прямоугольники рисуются просто с помощью нажатия **`ЛКМ`** по `scene`.

Принцип работы:

1. Нажимаем левой кнопкой мыши по области `scene` и не отпускаем ее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Протягивая зажатую кнопку мыши, наш прямоугольник постепенно появляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Разжимаем кнопку мыши чтобы построить прямоугольник (в конечной точке - разжимаем левую кнопку мыши)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.py**:

```python
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
 
class GraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    clicked = pyqtSignal(QPointF)
 
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        sp = event.scenePos()
        self.clicked.emit(sp)
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
 
class Editor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(520, 550)
 
        self.grview = QGraphicsView()
        self.grview.scale(1, -1)
 
        self.scene = GraphicsScene()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.scene.setSceneRect(-250, -250, 500, 500)
 
        self.grview.setScene(self.scene)
 
        self.pen = QPen(Qt.red)
        self.brush = QBrush(Qt.green)
        self.scene.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)
 
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.grview)
        self.show()
 
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        rect = self.scene.addRect(self.x, self.y, 100, 100, self.pen, self.brush)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        super(Editor, self).mousePressEvent(event)
 
    def handle_clicked(self, p):
        self.x = p.x()
        self.y = p.y()
        print(self.x)
 
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = Editor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Что-то нарисовал, проверьте.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SceneClass(QGraphicsScene):
    grid = 30

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QGraphicsScene.__init__(self, QRectF(-1000, -1000, 2000, 2000), parent)
        self._rect = QRectF() 
        self._flag = False 

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        if self._flag: self._rect = rect
        
        painter.fillRect(rect, QColor(50, 50, 50))
        left = int(rect.left()) - int((rect.left()) % self.grid)
        top = int(rect.top()) - int((rect.top()) % self.grid)
        right = int(rect.right())
        bottom = int(rect.bottom())
        lines = []
        for x in range(left, right, self.grid):
            lines.append(QLineF(x, top, x, bottom))  # QLine QLineF
        for y in range(top, bottom, self.grid):
            lines.append(QLineF(left, y, right, y))  # QLine QLineF
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(150, 50, 50)))
        painter.drawLines(lines)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._flag = True
        QGraphicsScene.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        items = self.items(event.scenePos())
        self._flag = False
        if not items:
            item = QGraphicsRectItem(self._rect)
            item.setZValue(1)
            item.setBrush(QColor(0, 230, 230, 100))   
            item.setFlags(  QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable 
                          | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable 
                          | QGraphicsItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges
                         )        
            self.addItem(item)
            self._rect = QRectF()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        

class ViewClass(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ViewClass, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setDragMode(QGraphicsView.RubberBandDrag)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        self.scene = SceneClass()
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        

class WindowClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.view = ViewClass()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    wd = WindowClass()
    wd.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @pythmy что не так ?